# Increasing variable count on imagemap click

Tags: javascript, html, click, imagemap

I have an imagemap and wanted to keep track of how many times it had been clicked in javascript, but I have no idea how I would record the click count.

```
<p>
    <img src="image.png" alt="missing" width="396" height="376" border="0" usemap="#thatPageMap" />

    <map name="imageMap" id="thatPageMap">
        <area shape="poly" coords="0,376,-3,269,50,251,60,234,71,225,76,192,69,178,44,127,50,82,73,62,94,48,69,46,108,30,145,20,162,29,162,16,183,34,193,41,228,35,247,38,225,47,242,47,279,53,306,78,324,117,326,150,335,179,327,200,327,221,351,234,357,263,393,275,394,378" href="thatpage.com" alt="Refresh" />
    </map>
</p>
```

Above is the imagemap and below is the javascript and the paragraph with the counted ID.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var count;

    document.getElementById("counted").innerHTML = "This has been clicked " + count + " times.";

</script>

<p id="counted"></p>
```

How can I increase the variable count each time the imagemap is clicked?

Comment: [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) then go learn to do it with jQuery or similar library for compatability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    function updateCounter( ) {
        count++;  
        document.getElementById("counted").innerHTML = "This has been clicked " + count + " times.";
    }
</script>

<p id="counted"></p>

<map name="imageMap" id="thatPageMap" onclick="updateCounter()">
    <area shape="poly" coords="0,376,-3,269,50,251,60,234,71,225,76,192,69,178,44,127,50,82,73,62,94,48,69,46,108,30,145,20,162,29,162,16,183,34,193,41,228,35,247,38,225,47,242,47,279,53,306,78,324,117,326,150,335,179,327,200,327,221,351,234,357,263,393,275,394,378" href="thatpage.com" alt="Refresh" />
</map>
```

Comment: So simple :P Thanks a lot!

The count is a count of how many times the page has been refreshed, using cookies to store the variable, works perfectly.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/PUs9g/

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for this basic functional?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to increase the click count and then call that from the onclick on the area.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var count;

    function clicked() {
        count = count + 1;
        document.getElementById("counted").innerHTML = "This has been clicked " + count + " times.";
   }



</script>


<p>
    <img src="image.png" alt="missing" width="396" height="376" border="0" usemap="#thatPageMap" />

    <map name="imageMap" id="thatPageMap">
        <area onclick="clicked();" shape="poly" coords="0,376,-3,269,50,251,60,234,71,225,76,192,69,178,44,127,50,82,73,62,94,48,69,46,108,30,145,20,162,29,162,16,183,34,193,41,228,35,247,38,225,47,242,47,279,53,306,78,324,117,326,150,335,179,327,200,327,221,351,234,357,263,393,275,394,378" href="thatpage.com" alt="Refresh" />
    </map>
</p>
```

or alternatively add the onclick to the map itself. But if you are counting a specific area, call it from there.

Comment: At first call it will be `undefined1` as you don't add devault value to `count` variable.

Answer (score 0):

if you define your counter without the keyword var it is a global variable.

you only need to change

```
var count;
```

to

```
count;
```

Comment: And why you need to add `count` variabe to global scope?

Comment: your solution is more elegant ;)